# Fluent Design System - Devices Supported

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I have an UWP app published in Microsoft/Windows Store (available in Windows 10 Desktop and Windows 10 Mobile), and I want update my app to Fluent Design System but I have an doubt.
Fluent Design system dont "exists" in Windows 10 Mobile, right? (transparent background, etc.)
With the update for the Fluent Design System, I want to change the look of my application (just make a few design changes), but I want devices that do not support the Fluent Design System (version of the anniversary update or before)to have access to the application but without the Fluent Design System changes.

It is possible? Do I have to create a new project?

Comment: Create two package one with  anniversary only targeted to arm and another with creator or fall creator sdk only targeted to x86, and x64. With same version and upload both package. And check mobile for that anniversary package a and pc for x86,x64 package, but some phone is updated to creator and fall creator update so that devices can use fluent design system and currently i am using creators 15063 version in my phone and soon try to upgrading to fall creator using insider program

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new project.

As Shubham said you can create specific package for it. However as ARM package does not only specific to Phone device, it is not a perfect idea here.

Official doc has already shared us the right way for solving this kind of problem:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-apps

For coding part, you can perform API checks with the help of this API:

```
   bool isScannerDeviceContract_1_Present =
    Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent
        ("Windows.Devices.Scanners.ScannerDeviceContract", 1);
```

For XAML, you can consider write Conditional XAML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml

In this way you can write version adaptive apps.